# Is composition an operation on the set of all continuous mappings from R to R?

Tags: abstract-algebra

After reading the same two pages in my algebra book over and over, all I've gotten is that an operation just has to be closed in the set under a mapping.

I guess composition wouldn't be an operation if there was somehow a mapping that took it into the complex set.

Comment: Well, yes. As you point out, domain must equal range to stay within a group. So mapping to $\mathbb{R}$ = good; to $\mathbb{C}$ == not good (in the 2 cases you describe).

Comment: @A USF Bull You should write your question in the question body instead of just the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a binary operation $*$ on a set $A$ is a mapping $ *:A\times A\to A$. Given $(a,b)\in A\times A$, it's usual to write $a*b$ to mean the "formally correct" $*(a,b)$.

Let's now consider your example and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Could it be that the "correspondence" $\circ$ is in fact a function (or mapping)?

Let $(f,g)\in \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}$. We wish to prove that $\circ (f,g)\in \mathcal{F}$, i.e., $f\circ g \in \mathcal{F}$.

Since $g$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ we know that $f\circ g$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Therefore, the only thing left to guarantee that $f\circ g \in \mathcal{F}$, is to show that $f\circ g$ is continuous. That follows from real analysis theory or Jacob's answer.

From here, one can conclude that it's not possible for elements of $\mathcal{F}$ to somehow map to set not contained in $\mathbb{R}$. This means that your "somehow" possibility can't happen.

I interpreted "*somehow a mapping that took it into the complex set*" as *"somehow a map that took it outside the real numbers*", because, of course, $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Would it be stupid to ask why it has to be continuous?

Comment: @A USF Bull Not at all, in fact I think it's good that you doubt everything. However, as I said in my post, the answer to that comes from real analysis. Jacob justifies that fact on his answer and Martin gives an alternative solution to that problem on a comment. If you want a more detailed answer on why the composition of two continuous functions is continuous, I suggest you ask a new question and give a good ammount of background regarding what you know about calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This follows because if $f$ is continuous and $g$ is continuous then $f\circ g$ is continuous. One sees for instance from the sequential definition of continuity that if $x_n \rightarrow x$ that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(g(x_n))=f\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g(x_n)\right)=f\circ g \left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n\right)=f(g(x)).$$

Comment: Or $U$ open $\Rightarrow$ $f^{-1}(U)$ open $\Rightarrow$ $(fg)^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ open.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, Yes that's probably the better argument. For some reason I could only remember $\varepsilon-\delta$ and sequential definitions of continuity while writing this answer.