# Sums of functions and mapping

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Given $f_1,f_2: X \to X$ where $X$ is a metric space and the mappings are continuous and bounded (and therefore Lipschitz). Does it necessarily follow that $$(f_1+f_2)(x) = f_1(x)+f_2(x)$$ for some $x \in X$?

I've seen the property that $(x+y)(t) = x(t) + y(t)$ a couple of times in my life in calculus or in linear algebra sometimes. Are there times when it doesn't hold?

Does the above question hold if $X$ is a normed space?

Comment: What's $f_1+f_2$? Is it $f_1 \circ f_2$?

Comment: Adding functions, not taking compositions

Comment: How do you define that sum?

Comment: Sorry I am kinda lost here. Could you show me an example of your question?

Comment: So am I. Can you tell me, please, how exactly you construction $f_1+f_2$ maps some number $x \in X$ to some other number $y \in X$? Functions are defined by their mapping.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. We aren't given what $f_1$, $f_2$, or $f_1 + f_2$ are. All we know is that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are Lipschitz. In fact we could even make a stricter condition that the maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ are contractions

Comment: @sizz No, this has nothing to do with lipschitz functions or metric spaces. I's a more universal concept. Read my answer.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of "binary operation"?

Comment: @sizz It should be defined somehow, otherwise it's completely arbitrary, so there's no way to check identities. For example, I __define__ that $f_1+f_2$ maps $x$ as $f_1(x)\cdot f_2(x)$, and in this case, obviously, $(f_1+f_2)(x) \neq f_1(x)+f_2(x)$. I just thought maybe your "sum" is defined somehow and you just forgot to mention it.

Comment: @sizz I added some stuff to the answer.

Comment: @Kaster, just clarifying your example. Do you mean $f_1 + f_2 : (X,  +) \to (X,\cdot)$?

Comment: @sizz Right, if $X \in \mathbb R$, and $+/-$ operations are as usual. Please read what __Git Gud__ wrote below as an answer, it's thoroughly clarified there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the definition of $f+g$?

Given two maps $f,g:X\to A$, where $A,X$ are sets such that there is a 'sum' $+_A$ in $A$, $f+g$ is **defined** by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+_Ag(x)$, for all $x\in X$.

Note that I used two different symbols to denote a sum, that's because they are two different sums. The sum $+$ in $f+g$ is a binary operation defined in the set of all maps from $X$ to $A$, $A^X$, while the sum $+_A$ is a binary operation defined in $A$.

Almost always mathematicians will write $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, but that's essetially incorrect because the same symbol $+$ is used to denote two different things. What they mean is what I wrote above.

Comment: Do you think question might serve as an answer? :)

Comment: @Kaster Yes. ${}{}{}$

Comment: So, in this case question is rhetorical, because identity is valid by definition, since $+_A \equiv +$ in $X$.

Comment: @Kaster It's not rethorical. I believe the OP doesn't understand the definition of $f+g$.

Comment: What if we assume it is the *same* binary operation?

Comment: @sizz By definition, a [binary operation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288219/is-composition-an-operation-on-the-set-of-all-continuous-mappings-from-r-to-r) on a set $S$ is a map $\varphi :S\times S\to S$. Assuming $+$=$+_A$ implies assuming that $A^X=A$ (because if two functions are equal, then they must have the same domain).

Comment: Sorry if I am being really stupid now, but can we assume that $A^x = A$ in my question?

Comment: @sizz No, because $A^X$ and $A$ have different cardinalities.

Comment: But then that would mean the mapping is meaningless and so is my question...

Comment: What if $X$ is the set of all continuous functions on a compact interval?

Comment: @sizz In our notation I think you mean to consider the set $\{ f\in A^X | f \text{ is continuous} \}$, where $X$ is a compact interval. This set also differs in cardinality from $A$. I gotta go now. Try to understand the first three lines of my answer, otherwise I'll answer back later if no one else does in the mean time.